# Flex 4 SDK Class not found in Flex-mojos

Tags: apache-flex, flexmojos

When I try to build the project I get

```
Definition spark.components.gridClasses:CellRegion could not be found.
```

This class is contained in com/adobe/flex/framework/spark/4.5.0.17855/spark-4.5.0.17855.swc which is included in the library-path by the flex-mojo compiler but I still get the error.

I use flex-mojos 3.9 and Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your configuration section of the flexmojos plugin:

```
<swfVersion>11</swfVersion>
```

I had a similar problem and that change fixed it.